# ajax does not refresh the page in mvc3

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3, asp.net-ajax

I have 2 radio buttons
1 to to accept the work and give an option for file upload
and on second button the file upload option will not be given

On click of submit this data is saved in the database

i wrote ajax function for this as follows:

```
    $(document).ready(function () {
            $('#rmrkRjct').click(function () {
        var url1 = "/Mycontroller/function1";
        $.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            url: url1,
            success: function () {

            }
        });
    });
```

this is calling my function bt does not show me updated view

Comment: Could you please provide more info.

Answer (score 2):

You don't seem to be doing much in your `success` callback. It's empty. So when the AJAX request completes this emptiness gets executed and you get the expected result: nothing happens. If the controller action that you have invoked returns some partial view you might want to refresh your DOM with it:

```
success: function (result) {
    $('#id_of_some_element_that_you_want_to_refresh').html(result);
}
```

Comment: I am doing this inside the table where only on selection of approve redio button, i need to show the row which include option for uploding the file....can u help me with that

Comment: What do you want to show/update on this row? From what I can see right now your controller action returns a full View, so it is unlikely that it is adapted for AJAX.

Comment: i need to show the file upload option only on click of Approve radio button if reject is clicked , that option shd not be shown....

Comment: Why are you using AJAX? Can't you simply use .hide()/.show() directly on the client?

Comment: :I tried that earlier bt it gives me a hollow space on form at starting